# Math.Round vs String.Format

Tags: c#

I need double value to be rounded to 2 digits.
What is preferrable?

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
Math.Round(123.4567, 2)                   // "123.46"
```

Comment: Well they need not be the same, so you may prefer `Math.Round` and use its rounding options ,Also check this [string format rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226081/why-does-net-use-a-rounding-algorithm-in-string-format-that-is-inconsistent-wit)

Comment: On the off-chance that you are storing currency as double, you should really consider using decimal. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: `Math.Round(double,digits)` with digits>0 is conceptually very unclean. I think it should never be used. `double` is a binary floating point number and thus has no well defined concept of decimal digits. If you need to round a number to a certain number of decimal digits, use `Decimal`, not `Double`.

Comment: Note the the first one uses "away from zero" rounding and the second one uses "to even". The second one let's you specify the type of rounding through an overload, but default by default it's "to even".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are different functions, if you need the output to be displayed, use the first one (that also forces decimals to appear). You will avoid the overhead of the inevitable .ToString() that will occur if the variable is of type double.

Note that the second one rounds the number but if it's an integer result, you will get just the integer (ie: 7 vs 7.00)

Answer (score 18):

`Math.Round(double,digits)` with digits>0 is conceptually very unclean. But I think it should never be used. `double` is a binary floating point number and thus has no well-defined concept of decimal digits.

I recommend using `string.Format`, or just `ToString("0.00")` when you only need to round for decimal display purposes, and `decimal.Round` if you need to round the actual number(for example using it in further calculations).

Note: With `decimal.Round` you can specify a [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) mode. It's common to want `AwayFromZero` rounding, not `ToEven` rounding.

With `ToEven` rounding `0.005m` gets rounded to `0.00` and `0.015` gets rounded to `0.02`. That's not what most people expect.

Comparisons:

- ToEven: 3.75 rounds to 3.8
- ToEven: 3.85 rounds to **3.8** *(That's not what most people expect)*
- AwayFromZero: 3.75 rounds to 3.8
- AwayFromZero: 3.85 rounds to **3.9**

for more information see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx

Comment: ...what to do if I'm not "most people"?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe @CodesInChaos is not saying people never expect .5's to round down, they just expect it to round consistently (ie. if 3.75 rounds up, so 3.85 should behave similarly.

Comment: @AndriyK just leave the `MidpointRounding` as `ToEven`? Not sure I get your point.

Comment: @Ruben9922, my point is that when you adhere to ToString or string.Format, you don't have this option, it will always round away, as "most people expect".

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you want to do with it.

`String.Format` will return a string, `Math.Round(double)` will return a double.

Answer (score 1):

the former outputs a string, the latter a double. What's your use of the result ? The answer of this will give the answer of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return this value as a `string` then `String.Format` is better and if you want to return this value as a `double` in that case `Math.Round` is better. It totally depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Round` will not add any decimal places if there aren't any to begin with. `String.Format` will.
e.g.:  `Math.Round(2)` returns 2; 
     `String.Format("{0:0.00}",2)` returns 2.00;